# asp.net mvc - Data lost on post back

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, validation, postback

I have a form that only has a checkbox. If the checkbox is not checked then the page won't be valid and won't submit the data. On the view I have out putted some fields from the model object, just to let the user know what they are deleting. When I click the Submit button and the model state is not valid the page will show the validation error but the data from the model is no longer there!

Does anyone know how I can persist this data without making another call to the database to populate the model object?

Thanks

Comment: Are you returning the viewmodel as part of your return View() statement once validation fails?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net MVC will not magically persist model info.

You need to either include it in hidden fields in the form (which an attacker can modify), or re-fetch it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't repopulate the Model from the DB, you have to postback all the data, using hidden fields for example.

Anyway, I don't understand how the model validation could fail, being just a checkbox :/.

Comment: the model validation works great, it's only a cosmetic problem really